# Cycles in interface hierarchies

Tags: java, interface

With interfaces structure like this:

[image]

Why does not A-D-F yield an error since it is a cycle?

Note: An arrow A->B means A extends B

Comment: What do the arrows denote?

Comment: Does the direction of the arrow mean is subinterface or is superinterface?

Comment: an arrow A->B means A extends B

Comment: @user3520274 Could you please express these three interfaces in terms of Java code, and make sure that it indeed does not yield an error? Because I strongly suspect that it does yield an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to interpret your diagram in code as follows:

```
interface A extends B, C, D { }
interface B { }
interface C { }
interface D extends F{ }
interface E extends F{ }
interface F extends A{ }
```

And the compiler fails with the error:

```
java: cyclic inheritance involving A
```

So, as expected, cyclic inheritance is not allowed.

The error goes away if `F` does **not** extend `A`.

Answer (score 3):

It does yield an error, have you tried it?

```
interface A extends D {} // error on this line: The hierarchy of the type A is inconsistent
interface D extends F {} // error on this line: The hierarchy of the type D is inconsistent
interface F extends A {} // error on this line: Cycle detected: a cycle exists in the type hierarchy between F and A
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the following insane usage:

```
interface I {
    static final I CONSTANT = new C();
    ...
}

class C implements I {
}
```

The reason that this works, is that the .class (like a binary .obj) contains symbolic information on its imports. So a .java can be compiled to a .class. And then the linkage against other .class files may be done.

For the same reason (loose linkage) execution may fail, when compiled with a different version of a jar than at run-time.

Some compilers might balk at specific cycles though.

---

***One addition though***

If one interface uses constants from another interface, upon compilation those constants are stored in the .class file, and in effect the imports disappear. In that case there is at least one compiler, that does not detect dependencies, and a cycle may be broken. This might even lead to wrong, stale constants; an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

error is at D extends F and E extends F and F extends A...
because JAVA won't support Multiple Inheritance... that is why Interface is been introduced

Comment: It does support multiple interface inheritance. The problem is with the cycle.